# How to set primary key in Swift for Realm model

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using Realm in a new iOS Swift project.  I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 with iOS SDK 8.0 and Realm 0.85.0

I'm trying to use the new Realm primary key feature so I can do an `addOrUpdateObject`.

Here is a sample model:

```
import Foundation
import Realm

class Foo: RLMObject {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var title = ""

    func primaryKey() -> Int {
        return id
    }
}
```

And how I'm trying to add/update a new object:

```
let foo = Foo()
foo.title = titleField.text
foo.id = 1

// Get the default Realm
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

// Add to the Realm inside a transaction
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
realm.addOrUpdateObject(foo)
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

I get this error:

> RLMExecption', reason: ''Foo' does not have a primary key and can not
>   be updated

Here are the docs on the primary key.  I'm probably not setting it correctly:
<strike>http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.85.0/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/primaryKey</strike>

Latest docs are here now: 
https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/primaryKey

Comment: broken link to the realm.io doc

Comment: We've moved our "cocoa" docs to "objc" when we launched Realm Swift, so try this link instead: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/primaryKey

We're setting up redirects from old links so this doesn't cause as much confusion in the future.

Comment: The redirect from the old links to the new docs doesn't seem to be working so I updated my question with the new link.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

As of Realm Swift v10.10.0, you declare a primary key with `@Persisted(primaryKey: true)`:

```swift
class Foo: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id = 0
    @Persisted var title = ""
}
```

---

Older versions:

`primaryKey` needs to be a class function which returns the name of the property which is the primary key, not an instance method which returns the value of the primary key.

```
@objcMembers class Foo: RLMObject {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var title = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes these were my problems.  Also, to get it working I to add 'override' to override the declaration.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the "override" keyword needed for Realm to correctly call the custom class function

Comment: For some reason I get an "invalid redeclaration of 'primaryKey()'" error. Can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: @Entalpi I updated the docs http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.89.2/#customizing-models, are you still seeing any errors? Feel free to message on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/realm-cocoa if you are, w/ a sample of your code

Comment: Per @CherryKuczery, the return type is optional. If I had enough reputation, I'd just merge the two answers.

Answer (score 8):

The return type of `primaryKey()` is optional:

```
class Foo: RLMObject {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var title = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this, looks like the accepted answer changed to reflect the optional return type as well.

Answer (score 8):

**For Swift 5:**

```
import RealmSwift

     class Signature: Object {

           @objc dynamic var id = ""

            override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
                return "id"
            }
      }
```

To avoid: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Primary key property 'id' does not exist on object.

Comment: This answer saved my day! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Realm 10.12.0 & Swift 5**

Legacy property declarations using @objc:

```
import RealmSwift

class Signature: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

When using @Persisted, use @Persisted(primaryKey: true) instead:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class MyModel: Object {
    @Persisted var pan: String?
    @Persisted var exp: String?
    @Persisted var cvv: String?
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var myId: String?
    
    override init() {}
    
    init(pan: String, exp: String, cvv2: String) {
        super.init()
        self.pan = pan
        self.exp = exp
        self.cvv = cvv2
    }
}
```