# iOS: Realm, check if the object is nil

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have this code where I populate an array:

```
func loadObjectsFromRealm() {
    private var myObjects: [MyObjects] = []
    guard let realm = try? Realm() else { return }
    myObjects = realmUtility.getAll(realm)
}
```

how can I check if the object is nil or not when I am going to use them?
For example:

```
func getFirst() {
var myFirstObj = myObjects[0]    
}
```

Is there something to check if the object `myFirstObject` is real or not?

Comment: I am not much concerned with the issue, but i think guard will not allow the nil object to be store in your realm as it will execute the else block and return. so no need to check for nil latter. Are you getting any nil object??

Comment: If your concern is to check nil
You can do by this

        if (myFirstObj == nil){
            print("No object to see here")
        }else{
            print("myFirstObj = \(myFirstObj)");
        }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safe (bounds-checked) array lookup in Swift, through optional bindings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329186/safe-bounds-checked-array-lookup-in-swift-through-optional-bindings)

Comment: Could you accept one of these answers atleast?

Answer (score 3):

```
// Check for specific object with primary key

func objectExist (id: String) -> Bool {
        return realm.object(ofType: MyObject.self, forPrimaryKey: id) != nil
}

// Returns true or false
objectExist(id: "1")
```

Comment: The ternary expression is not necessary here. The boolean comparison will return what you want directly without having to add any extra syntax

Comment: Thanks, changed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try an usual Swift if statement:

```
if let myFirstObj = myObjects.first
   // Do anything with the first object
} else {
   print("No first object!")
}
```

I think that's enough for this case.

Comment: Using subscripts does not check whether or not the index is valid, use `.first` instead.

Comment: I wrote first... but it could have whatever index

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment on the answer by @andromedainiative, but I don't have enough rep points.

'id' can't be a String - needs to be an Int;

```
func objectExists(id: Int) -> Bool {
        return realm.object(ofType: MyObject.self, forPrimaryKey: id) != nil
    }

//Returns true of false

objectExists(1)
```

Comment: That is not true at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152254/how-to-set-primary-key-in-swift-for-realm-model

Comment: @andromedainiative.  Checking the id using an Int is working 100% for me.  Were you able to get it working using the String value?  I noticed the answer you're referencing is a couple years old.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it following way, you can check like this. Here I have just created a nil object and checked, you can do the same for your object

```
 let obj :UserProfile? = nil;

    if (obj == nil){
        print("nil objUser");
    }else{
        print("objUser = \(objUser)")
    }
```

**output** : **nil objUser**

Answer (score 0):

you may check object is really exist before access it

```
if var myObj: MyObjects = myObjects.indices.contains(index) ? myObjects[index] : nil {
    // myObj is exist
}
```